# PHP library to transform Excel .xls .xlsx to OpenDocument .ods

Tags: linux, php, document-converter, microsoft-excel, libreoffice

I want to automatically convert Excel files (.xls, .xlsx) to OpenDocument spreadsheets (.ods)

Is there a PHP library for that?

Or at least a command-line utility that I could call from PHP?

Comment: .odf is for mathematical equations; probably you meant .ods?

Comment: I was going to suggest [PHPExcel](https://github.com/PHPOffice/PHPExcel/blob/develop/Documentation/markdown/Overview/10-Reading-and-Writing.md) since I've used that for reading a few spreadsheet types but I just checked and it can't *write* to OpenDocument only read.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[unoconv](http://dag.wiee.rs/home-made/unoconv/) does this.

```
<?php
exec('unoconv -f ods -o output.ods input.xlsx');
```